# Unable to update particular column of mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am not able to update a particular column of my database. In my database there is a "conditions" column which has a default value of "pending". I want to update this column with value "accept", but I am unable to do so.

My routes.php

```
Route::get('accept/{id}',array(
    'as'=>'accept-product',
    'uses'=>'GoodsController@updateProduct
));
```

My controller:

```
public function updateProduct($id) 
{
    $product = Products::findOrFail($id);
    $product->conditions = 'accept';
    $product->save();
}
```

My view:

```
@foreach($product as $productAccept)
    <a href="{{URL::route('accept-product')}}/{!! $productAccept->id !!}   ">Accept</a>
@endforeach
```

When I clicked accept button, the url is like this

`http://localhost/project/public/accept/{id}`

Which I want like this:

`http://localhost/project/public/accept/7`

I mean I am unable to replace `{id}` to integer like `7`,`8` etc.

Is something wrong in my `routes`?

Comment: While the answers below are correct, you should make sure you are checking if the product you're attempting to edit actually exists before trying to edit it.

Comment: @Seer Why? Just curious.

Comment: Because if it doesn't exist, I'm guessing this would throw an exception, which would cause an HTTP 500, instead of something useful to the user like an HTTP 404.

Answer (score 5):

Your defined route expects one extra parameter - id. You need to pass the product id in the route function as extra parameter like this:

```
 <a href="{{URL::route('accept-product', ['id' => $productAccept->id])}}">Accept</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
<a href="{{ route('accept-product', $productAccept->id)}}">Accept</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

use url as that

```
<a href="{!! URL::to('accept/$productAccept->id') !!}">Accept</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@foreach($product as $productAccept)
    <a href="{{route('accept-product', ['id' => $productAccept->id] )}}">Accept</a>
@endforeach
```

Your problem is from this: `/{!! $productAccept->id !!}`

Answer (score 0):

The most apparent issue that I see is may be that the the page is not being redirecting properly. I mean laravel may not be hitting that method of that controller and because there are no error message I am not sure.

One problem that can be is that you have already defined the route before somewhere in the code and it is being overwritten. If there are any error messages please share.

There are few improvements that I can see that you can make to the code above.
1. change

```
@foreach($product as $productAccept)
    <a href="{{URL::route('accept-product')}}/{!! $productAccept->id !!}   ">Accept</a>
@endforeach
```

to

```
@foreach($product as $productAccept)
    <a href="{{ route('accept-product', [$productAccept->id]) }}">Accept</a>
@endforeach
```

you can pass the id as second parameter to the `route` function( or `URL::route`), route which is a helper function same same `URL::route`

2. You can do model binding

`Route::model('product', 'Products');`

and the route would be

```
Route::get('accept/{product}',array(
    'as'=>'accept-product',
    'uses'=>'GoodsController@updateProduct
));
```

and you can get product in the controller as

```
public function updateProduct($product ) 
{
    $product->conditions = 'accept';
    $product->save();
}
```